# Pre-fill JSF form on button before final form submit

Tags: forms, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, lifecycle

I would like to pre-fill form, but not pre-fill while loading page but when user pushes button. Like "fill form with informations about product depending on its ID (user have to write it)". You can see example on picture that is linked below. This commandButton "Fetch data" make his job and fills fields on the form but when I submit form, values for product name, weight and descriptions are NULL, and that is very likely because of JSF lifecycle (after first submit application goes to steps 5 and 6 in JSF lifecycle), could somebody help me with it? Thanks

[Screenshot - Form example](http://i60.tinypic.com/2ns5kpu.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<f:view
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>

     <h:head>

    </h:head>
        <h:body style="vertical-align:middle;margin:auto">
            <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <p:growl id="growl" life="2000" />

            <div id="container">
                   <div class="divs">


                        <p class="header_single">Example</p>
                        <table class="tablica">
                          <tr>                        
                            <td>
                                <p:outputLabel for="p_id" value="Product ID:*" styleClass="f_text" />  
                                <p:inputText id="p_id" value="#{formValidationBean1.mbo}" required="true" requiredMessage="Required field">
                                    <f:ajax event="blur" render="err_msg1"/>
                                </p:inputText>  
                            </td>  

                            <td class="butt">
                                <p>
                                    <p:commandButton value="Fetch data" actionListener="#{formValidationBean1.fillForm}" update="p_name p_weight p_desc" icon="ui-icon-refresh" /> 

                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p>
                                    <p:message id="err_msg1" for="p_id" />
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p:outputLabel for="p_name" value="Product name:*" styleClass="f_text" />  
                                <p:inputText id="p_name" value="#{formValidationBean1.pName}" readonly="true"></p:inputText> 

                            </td>                             
                            <td>
                                <p:message for="p_name" display="text" />
                            </td> 

                            <td>

                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>


                          </tr> 
                          <tr>    
                            <td>
                                <p:outputLabel for="p_weight" value="Product weight:" styleClass="f_text" /> 
                                <p:inputText id="p_weight" value="#{formValidationBean1.pWeight}" readonly="true"></p:inputText>  
                            </td>                             
                            <td>
                                <p:message for="p_weight" display="text" />
                            </td>                           
                            <td>
                                <p:outputLabel for="p_desc" value="Product description:" styleClass="f_text" /> 
                                <p:inputText id="p_desc" value="#{formValidationBean1.pDesc}" readonly="true"></p:inputText>                          
                            </td>                               
                            <td>
                                <p:message for="p_desc" display="text" /> 
                            </td>                   

                          </tr>

                        </table>

                </div>

                <div class="submit">
                    <p:commandButton value="Submit" id="ajax" update="growl" actionListener="#{formValidationBean1.someAction}" styleClass="button" />

                </div>


            </div>
            </h:form>          
          </h:body>
</f:view>
```

Comment: might be an issue about `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute of form. are you uploading any files within this form?

Comment: Yes, this is just example to simplify things, but in my real form I have an attachment also. My button "Fetch data" fill the form without problem, but on submit there are null values in fields

Comment: uploading the file in a separate form and removing `enctype` from this one would be a solution, even if it's a work-around.

Comment: I've removed enctype attribute, but it's the same, fields are null in backing bean after final form submit...

Comment: two more questions then: 1- does the application hit field setter methods in debug mode? 2- what is your bean scope (hopefully not request)?